Navigate different cards to their respective page
I am trying to navigate different cards to their respective pages using react-router and        use-Navigate but can't ,as the onclick functionality is not working.
    import React from 'react';
import { Link  , useNavigate} from 'react-router-dom';

const Card = ({ id, imageSrc, title, text }) => (
  <Link to={`/card/${id}`} className="card-link">
    <div className="rounded-lg overflow-hidden shadow-lg hover:shadow-xl transition duration-300">
      <img src={imageSrc} alt="Card" className="w-full h-auto" />
      <div className="p-4">
        <h3 className="text-xl font-semibold mb-2">{title}</h3>
        <p className="text-gray-700">{text}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </Link>
);

const Action = () => {
  const cardsData = [
    { id: 1, imageSrc: '/images/tokyo_ghoul.jpg', title: 'Title 1', text: 'The story follows Ken Kaneki, a student who barely survives a deadly encounter with Rize Kamishiro,his date who reveals herself as a ghoul and tries to eat him. He is taken to the hospital in critical condition. ' },
    { id: 2, imageSrc: '/images/tomodachi.jpg', title: 'Title 2', text: 'High school student Yuuichi Katagiri cherishes his close circle of friends, composed of four classmates: Yutori Kokorogi,Shiho Sawaragi, Makoto Shibe, and Tenji Mikasa. However, when the funds for the upcoming school trip are stolen, the incident causes Shiho and Makoto—who had been tasked with collecting the money—to distance ' },
    { id: 3, imageSrc: '/images/Demon_Slayer.jpg', title: 'Title 3', text: "Ever since the death of his father, the burden of supporting the family has fallen upon Tanjirou Kamado's shoulders.Though living impoverished on a remote mountain, the Kamado family are able to enjoy a relatively peaceful and happy life.One day, Tanjirou decides to go down to the local village to make a" },
    { id: 4, imageSrc: '/images/onepiece2.jpg', title: 'Title 4', text: "A fleet of pirate ships with the same Jolly Roger are shown along with a man sporting said flag, Woonan.Next a night scene where piles of gold treasure are seen bright at sea with a silhouette of Woonan.  Then an island is shown while gold rains down as it fades out ending with a shot of a treasure map." },
    { id: 5, imageSrc: '/images/horimiya-img.jpg', title: 'Title 5', text: 'Admired at school for her friendly attitude and academic achievements, high school student Kyouko Hori has been hiding another side of herself.With her parents often away from home due to work, Hori also has to look after her younger brother and do the housework, leaving no opportunities .' },
    { id: 6, imageSrc: '/images/eminence.jpeg', title: 'Title 6', text: "Even in his past life, Cid's dream wasn't to become a protagonist or a final boss.He'd rather lie low as a minor character until it's prime time to reveal he's a mastermind...or at least, do the next best thing-pretend to be one! And now that he's been reborn into another world, he's ready to set the perfect conditions  to live out his dreams to the fullest." },
    // Add more card data as needed
  ];

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  const navigateToCardDetails = (id) => {
    // Navigate to the card details page based on the ID
    switch (id) {
      case 1:
        navigate(`/card/${id}`);
        break;
      // cases for other IDs...
      default:
        break;
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className="grid grid-cols-1 mt-[616px] sm:grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-4 gap-6 p-6">
      {cardsData.map(card => (
        <div key={card.id} onClick={() => navigateToCardDetails(card.id)}>
          <Card id={card.id} imageSrc={card.imageSrc} title={card.title} text={card.text} />
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Action;


In the Action component, I'm trying to navigate to different pages when clicking on each card using React Router's use-Navigate hook. However, the navigation doesn't seem to work as expected.

Assuming you have the router and routes setup and configured correctly then the Link should just work. The case 1: navigate(`/card/${id}`) only works when the id value used for the switch statement is 1. What exactly isn't working for you though? Please [edit] to clarify the problem and include a more complete [mcve] of the relevant router/routing code and any other UI code you feel would be helpful for us to see.





    <Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Action />} />
    <Route path="card1" element={<TokyoGhoul />} />
  </Routes>
  </div>
</Router>...this is my app.js code where navbar and sliding are withinthe same page as the cards and tokyo=ghoul is the page where i want the card1 to be directed.


import React from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

const Card = ({ id, imageSrc, title, text }) => (
  <Link to={`/card/${id}`} className="card-link">
    <div className="rounded-lg overflow-hidden shadow-lg hover:shadow-xl transition duration-300">
      <img src={imageSrc} alt="Card" className="w-full h-auto" />
      <div className="p-4">
        <h3 className="text-xl font-semibold mb-2">{title}</h3>
        <p className="text-gray-700">{text}</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </Link>
);

const Action = () => {
  const cardsData = [
    { id: 1, imageSrc: '/images/tokyo_ghoul.jpg', title: 'Title 1', text: 'The story follows Ken Kaneki, a student who barely survives a deadly encounter with Rize Kamishiro,his date who reveals herself as a ghoul and tries to eat him. He is taken to the hospital in critical condition. ' },
    { id: 2, imageSrc: '/images/tomodachi.jpg', title: 'Title 2', text: 'High school student Yuuichi Katagiri cherishes his close circle of friends, composed of four classmates: Yutori Kokorogi,Shiho Sawaragi, Makoto Shibe, and Tenji Mikasa. However, when the funds for the upcoming school trip are stolen, the incident causes Shiho and Makoto—who had been tasked with collecting the money—to distance ' },
    { id: 3, imageSrc: '/images/Demon_Slayer.jpg', title: 'Title 3', text: "Ever since the death of his father, the burden of supporting the family has fallen upon Tanjirou Kamado's shoulders.Though living impoverished on a remote mountain, the Kamado family are able to enjoy a relatively peaceful and happy life.One day, Tanjirou decides to go down to the local village to make a" },
    { id: 4, imageSrc: '/images/onepiece2.jpg', title: 'Title 4', text: "A fleet of pirate ships with the same Jolly Roger are shown along with a man sporting said flag, Woonan.Next a night scene where piles of gold treasure are seen bright at sea with a silhouette of Woonan.  Then an island is shown while gold rains down as it fades out ending with a shot of a treasure map." },
    { id: 5, imageSrc: '/images/horimiya-img.jpg', title: 'Title 5', text: 'Admired at school for her friendly attitude and academic achievements, high school student Kyouko Hori has been hiding another side of herself.With her parents often away from home due to work, Hori also has to look after her younger brother and do the housework, leaving no opportunities .' },
    { id: 6, imageSrc: '/images/eminence.jpeg', title: 'Title 6', text: "Even in his past life, Cid's dream wasn't to become a protagonist or a final boss.He'd rather lie low as a minor character until it's prime time to reveal he's a mastermind...or at least, do the next best thing-pretend to be one! And now that he's been reborn into another world, he's ready to set the perfect conditions  to live out his dreams to the fullest." },
    // Add more card data as needed
  ];

 

  return (
    <div className="grid grid-cols-1 mt-[616px] sm:grid-cols-2 md:grid-cols-3 lg:grid-cols-4 gap-6 p-6">
      {cardsData.map(card => (
      
          <Card key={card.id} id={card.id} imageSrc={card.imageSrc} title={card.title} text={card.text} />
     
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Action;

```This is my Cards content page code```






import './index.css'
import Navbar from "./components/Navbar/navbar.js";
import Sliding from './components/Sliding/sliding.js';
import Action from './components/collections/Action.js';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes } from 'react-router-dom';
import CardDetails from './components/CardDetails.js';

function App() {
  return (
    <Router> {/* Move the top-level Router here */}
      <div className="relative">
        <Navbar />
        <Sliding />
        
        <Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Action />} />
        <Route path="card/:id" element={<CardDetails />} />
        
      </Routes>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}

export default App;

This is my App.js Code
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import tokyo_ghoul from './collections/tokyo_ghoul';

const lookup = {
  1: tokyo_ghoul,
  // Add more mappings as needed
};

const CardDetails = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();
  const Details = lookup[id];

  return Details ? <Details /> : <div>No data found for id: {id}</div>;
};

export default CardDetails;

this is CardDetails code
But when i click on the card1 it still not navigating to tokyo_ghoul page

This looks like it should be a comment instead of a submitted answer.

You are trying to navigate to paths like "/card/1" and "/card/2", but render a route like "/card1", so path "/card/1" has no matching route.
Update the routing configuration to specify route paths that match the link paths you are targeting.
Example:
<Router>
  <div className="relative">
    <Navbar />
    <Sliding />
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Action />} />
      <Route path="card/1" element={<TokyoGhoul />} />
      <Route path="card/2" element={<Tomodachi />} />
      {/* etc */}
    </Routes>
  </div>
</Router>

or
<Router>
  <div className="relative">
    <Navbar />
    <Sliding />
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Action />} />
      <Route path="card">
        <Route path="1" element={<TokyoGhoul />} />
        <Route path="2" element={<Tomodachi />} />
        {/* etc */}
      </Route>
    </Routes>
  </div>
</Router>

The Link component rendered in Card should be sufficient enough to trigger a navigation action to the specific route.
const cardsData = [
  { id: 1, imageSrc: '/images/tokyo_ghoul.jpg', title: 'Title 1', text: '....' },
  { id: 2, imageSrc: '/images/tomodachi.jpg', title: 'Title 2', text: '....' },
  { id: 3, imageSrc: '/images/Demon_Slayer.jpg', title: 'Title 3', text: "...." },
  { id: 4, imageSrc: '/images/onepiece2.jpg', title: 'Title 4', text: "...." },
  { id: 5, imageSrc: '/images/horimiya-img.jpg', title: 'Title 5', text: '....' },
  { id: 6, imageSrc: '/images/eminence.jpeg', title: 'Title 6', text: "...." },
  // Add more card data as needed
];

const Action = () => {
  return (
    <div className="....">
      {cardsData.map(card => (
        <Card
          key={card.id}
          id={card.id}
          imageSrc={card.imageSrc}
          title={card.title}
          text={card.text}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

To avoid repetitive route code/logic like this it's a common practice to define a single route path with a dynamic path segment to match id values.
Example:
<Router>
  <div className="relative">
    <Navbar />
    <Sliding />
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Action />} />
      <Route path="card/:id" element={<CardDetails />} />
      {/* other routes */}
    </Routes>
  </div>
</Router>

This new CardDetails component would read the id value from the route path parameters and compute the correct UI to render.
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';
import {
  TokyoGhoul,
  Tomodachi,
  ....
} from '../components';

const lookup = {
  1: TokyoGhoul,
  2: Tomodachi,
  ... etc ...
};

const CardDetails = () => {
  const { id } = useParams();

  const Details = lookup[id];

  return Details ? <Details /> : <div>No data found</div>;
};


i have posted the updated code can you please check and tell me the issue in that code.

@AmanGupta You link to to={`/card/${id}`}, do you see the URL update to the correct expected path? Did you update the routes to be navigatable to?

i didn't understand .what do you mean

@AmanGupta I mean that in code you have <Link to={`/card/${id}`}>...</Link> so when you click this you navigate to something like "/card/1" or "/card/13". I'm asking you that when you do click on the cards and navigate, what is the URL path you get navigated to in the browser's address bar? The route paths you render and the links you use to navigate to them just need to match.

Yes, that's what i am saying that when i click on the card it doesn't navigate to any page nor the URL change

@AmanGupta I don't know what you are doing on your end, but the code I've suggested here works as expected and navigates to the specified target route. Can you create a running Codesandbox demo that reproduces the issue you see that we could inspect live?

The issue resolved ,the fault was from my side. Thanks for you help.

@AmanGupta Ah great to hear that. Welcome, happy to help. Cheers and good luck!
